# Vibrating hood at speeds greater than 100 kph on 2018 RAV4

Tags: toyota, vibration, rav4, hood

I've noticed that hood starts to vibrate at speeds greater than 100 kph. It's not something that annoys me too much but since my car is still under warranty I went to ask my dealer about it. From the dealership they told me that it's normal. Did anyone else experience this issue?

Since the dealership tried to upsell the breakpads on last regular service, I am not too keen on trusting them completely.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you explain further what you mean by "vibrating"? Is it the hood which you see vibrating, or is this something you feel? If you are seeing the hood vibrating, there should be rubber snubbers located at the front corners you can adjust to meet the hood, which should keep it from vibrating (at least you'll find these on most vehicles).

Comment: Just because it is normal does not make it acceptable, crappy build quality is no excuse.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks for the welcome. I just see the hood vibrating from my driver's seat. Apart from that I don't feel anything in the car itself. Actually, the part of the hood which vibrates the most is central part closest to the windshield.

Comment: If the vehicle is still under it's bumper-to-bumper warranty, I'd highly suggest you take it back to the dealership and tell them there's an issue.

Comment: It is a common problem, to the point that some Rav4's have been recalled in the past because their hood would fly open. I don't see a recall for your model year though - only older ones.